# Scroll Div with mouse move

Tags: javascript, html

I develop a webapplication for a special tablet (run under Linux OS). The touch screen events are detected by Chromium as mouse events. Therefore I use the following code to control the swipe gesture.

```js
var scrollStartPos=0;
document.getElementById("scrollable").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
 scrollStartPos = this.scrollTop + event.pageY;
 event.preventDefault();
},false);

document.getElementById("scrollable").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
 this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.pageY;
 event.preventDefault();
},false);
```

```css
.maindata{
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-right: 80px
}

.maindata table{
 border-spacing: 10px;
}
.maindata tr{
 border-bottom-width: 5px;
 line-height: 25px; 
}
#dsrcheadtc{
 widht: 40%;
}
#dsrcdatatd{
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 width: 60%
}
```

```html
<div class="maindata"><table class="dsrcdata"><tbody id="scrollable">
<tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">1
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">1
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">2
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">2
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">3
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">3
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">4
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">4
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">5
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">5
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">6
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">6
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">7
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">7
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">8
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">8
  </td></tr>
   <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">9
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">9
  </td></tr>
   <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">10
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">10
  </td></tr>
   <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">11
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">11
  </td></tr>
   <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">12
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">12
  </td></tr>
   <tr><td  id="dsrcheadtc">13
  </td><td  id="dsrcdatatd">13
  </td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

However the problem ist that if I touch on the screen the mouse jumps to the last touched position. Thats not what I want. I want that the user shoudl be able to swipe this div up and down like on the phone. But this does not work at the moment. Its hard to scroll down to the end of the div.

Comment: Why not use a library that does this?

Comment: Which one should I use?